# Which be form to use after "and" with I?

Tags: conjunctions, conjunction-reduction

How are these sentences usually joined using "and"?

- I am from Asia. I am an English language learner.

  - Is "I am from Asia and am an English language learner" correct?
- You are from Asia. You are an English language learner.

  - Is "You are from Asia and are an English language learner." correct?

Comment: The sequence of words **and am an English** is difficult to pronounce. Few English language speakers would use it. Although you could use the constructions you suggest, they are not idiomatic. Much simpler and more natural would be: **I am from Asia and I'm learning English** Or, less likely: **I'm learning English and I'm from Asia.**

Comment: Ok, thanks. But how do you join it without repeating the pronoun "I"?

Comment: They appear to be correct. You can omit or repeat the pronoun: "I am from Asia and I am an English language learner." "You are from Asia and you are an English language learner." It is probably more common to omit the repeated pronoun, but it is not required.

Comment: @RonaldSole I think you should post your comment as an answer. It's better than mine. In your suggested rewrites changing the order changes the emphasis.

Comment: It's true that contestants on University Challenge usually introduce themselves as *I am [name] from [hometown] and I'm studying [subject]*, but *I am from Asia and [I] am an English language learner* does sound a bit "robotic" to me. More naturally, perhaps, *I am an English language learner from Asia.*

Answer (score 1):

The sequence of words **and am an English** is difficult to pronounce.

Few English language speakers would use it.

Although you could use the constructions you suggest, they are not idiomatic.

Much simpler and more natural would be:

> I am from Asia and I'm learning English
> Or, less likely:
> I'm learning English and I'm from Asia.

Another possibility - with acknowledgement to FumbleFingers:

> I am an English language learner from Asia.

Answer (score 0):

Both rewritings are correct. You could leave out the second "am" in the single sentences.